# Symfony 1.4 module with coefficients

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I use symfony 1.4.15 with doctrine.  I have some static coefficients and I need to edit it value in backend. So I  generate admin module in backend, and allow admin to edit only it's value. And off delete and new actions. Is it true way?Is there another way to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this plug-in for a very similar problem before: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/csSettingsPlugin

You can retrieve settings stored in the database via

```
csSettings::get('setting_name')
```

and it falls back to

```
sfConfig::get('app_setting_name')
```

if none was found.

Check the README on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the best way to doit. 
Using a form you can configure your coefficientes widgets and validators.